# Return status code 4xx for client requests with invalid/unsupported Content-Type (like text/plain)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, content-type

I've implemented a RESTful API using ASP.NET Web API (included in ASP.NET MVC 4).

When a client requests my services with an unsupported Content-Type (like "text/plain"), I get the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No MediaTypeFormatter is available
>   to read an object of type [...] from content with media type
>   'text/plain'.

and my service returns a HTTP status code 500 and an error is logged/reported (I'm using ELMAH).

Unfortunately, I do not find an easy way to "catch" this type of unsupported client request. IMHO, the service should return a status code like 404 (not found) or 400 (bad request), because the error is not a server error (but a client side error).

In another SO question I found this answer [How do I configure the status code returned by my ASP.NET Web API service when the request has an unsupported Content-Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098097/how-do-i-configure-the-status-code-returned-by-my-asp-net-web-api-service-when-t#12099486) which shows a possible solution by implementing a custom DelegatingHandler.

So my question is: Do I miss something? Is there any ASP.NET Web API built-in functionality that targets this problem...

Comment: Good point Steve. I've updated my post to make my question more clear.

Answer (score 2):

I finally "fixed" the problem with a custom DelegatingHandler similar to this implementation 
[How do I configure the status code returned by my ASP.NET Web API service when the request has an unsupported Content-Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098097/how-do-i-configure-the-status-code-returned-by-my-asp-net-web-api-service-when-t#12099486).

You can find my implementation here: http://blog.janjonas.net/2012-09-05/asp_net-mvc_4_rc-web-api-return-http-status-code-4xx-invalidoperationexception-no-mediatypeformatter-available-read-object-type-content-media-type

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use your own custom DelegatingHandler or you can make your custom HttpModule
which will implement the IHttpModule and check the current http request and validate the request.